# Can't connect to Mongo atlas spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm having some issues connecting to my MongoDB Atlas collection. Using the connection instructions given by Mongo, I've done this in my project:

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
                "mongodb+srv://<admin>:<password>@cluster0-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");

            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
            MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
            database.getName();
```

but when I run it, the `UnknownHostExeption` is thrown, telling me that `cluster0-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net` is an unknown host. So I've tried connecting through mongo shell this way:

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net/test" --username username
```

it asked me for password, and this is what was printed:

> connecting to:
>   mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017/test?authSource=admin&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&ssl=true
>   2019-04-10T15:52:07.396+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Starting new replica set
>   monitor for
>   Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-00-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017
>   2019-04-10T15:52:07.835+0200 I NETWORK 
>   [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to
>   cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017 (1 connections now
>   open to cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017 with a 5
>   second timeout) 2019-04-10T15:52:07.837+0200 I NETWORK  [js]
>   Successfully connected to
>   cluster0-shard-00-00-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017 (1 connections now
>   open to cluster0-shard-00-00-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017 with a 5
>   second timeout) 2019-04-10T15:52:07.862+0200 I NETWORK 
>   [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] changing hosts to
>   Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017
>   from
>   Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net.:27017
>   2019-04-10T15:52:07.992+0200 I NETWORK 
>   [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to
>   cluster0-shard-00-00-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now
>   open to cluster0-shard-00-00-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 with a 5
>   second timeout) 2019-04-10T15:52:08.003+0200 I NETWORK  [js]
>   Successfully connected to
>   cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now
>   open to cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 with a 5
>   second timeout) 2019-04-10T15:52:08.245+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Marking
>   host cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 as failed ::
>   caused by :: Location40659: can't connect to new replica set master
>   [cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017], err: Location8000:
>   Authentication failed. 2019-04-10T15:52:08.289+0200 I NETWORK 
>   [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor] Successfully connected to
>   cluster0-shard-00-02-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 (1 connections now
>   open to cluster0-shard-00-02-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 with a 5
>   second timeout) 2019-04-10T15:52:08.406+0200 I NETWORK  [js] Marking
>   host cluster0-shard-00-00-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 as failed ::
>   caused by :: Location8000: can't authenticate against replica set node
>   cluster0-shard-00-00-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 :: caused by ::
>   Authentication failed. 2019-04-10T15:52:08.566+0200 I NETWORK  [js]
>   Marking host cluster0-shard-00-02-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 as
>   failed :: caused by :: Location8000: can't authenticate against
>   replica set node cluster0-shard-00-02-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 ::
>   caused by :: Authentication failed. 2019-04-10T15:52:08.734+0200 I
>   NETWORK  [js] Marking host
>   cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 as failed :: caused
>   by :: Location40659: can't connect to new replica set master
>   [cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017], err: Location8000:
>   Authentication failed. 2019-04-10T15:52:08.736+0200 E QUERY    [js]
>   Error: can't authenticate against replica set node
>   cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017 :: caused by :: can't
>   connect to new replica set master
>   [cluster0-shard-00-01-jufkk.gcp.mongodb.net:27017], err: Location8000:
>   Authentication failed. : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
>   @(connect):2:6 exception: connect failed

My credentials are correct. The username contains @, so I've tried both with %40 and without it, but the result is the same. How can I further check where's the problem?

Comment: Have you tried changing the username to something without special characters to see if that works?  Like making the username something like `myUser123`?

Comment: @MichaelPlatt unfortunately I can't change the username, since it's not my database :\

Comment: If it isn't your database then are you sure you have the right to connect?  Maybe they are blocking all IPs except a list of whitelisted IPs that they have?  Are you able to get in touch with someone and ask them about that?

Comment: From my browser I can connect to it

Comment: Are the login credentials the same you use for logging in through the web that you would through command line?  Also, when you log in through the browser can you connect to the mongo database through a terminal with those credentials?